# location.reload reloads most things

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, apache, cookies

I'm creating a multi-language site that knows the user's "navigation language" by a cookie I set called `nav_lang`. Currently, the way I have it set is that if the user selects to navigate by a new language, it sets the cookie to the language (e.g., Hindi) and runs location.reload().

I noticed while looking at Chrome's "inspect element" function, that it reloads the Javascript and font files from the server, rather than from cache. I want it to reload the page but not all the elements of it. Interestingly, the files being pulled from SDNs (e.g., jQuery) don't reload because a 304 Not Modified message is returned for those. Also, PNG files on my own server return 304 Not Modified, so do not re-download.

How can I configure the server so the location.reload() just reloads the page itself and not the auxiliary files (e.g., fonts, scripts, css, etc)? I imagine it's some setting in my Apache configuration. I'm running Apache 2.4.9, which is part of Bitnami's Lampstack version 5.4.30-0.

Comment: There seem to be people who enjoy downgrading questions for no apparent reason other than that it makes them feel powerful or something. It prevents people from feeling free to ask questions, I think. At least be cool enough to offer a reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

reload() method reloads from the browser cache.
You can force the the reload to get the page from server by setting the forceGet parameter to true: location.reload(true);

in your case, you need to setup expiration time for css, js, images and font in either .htaccess file in web directory or in apache's virtual host file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive on

# Perhaps better to whitelist expires rules? Perhaps.
  ExpiresDefault                          "access plus 1 month"

# cache.appcache needs re-requests in FF 3.6 (thx Remy ~Introducing HTML5)
  ExpiresByType text/cache-manifest       "access plus 0 seconds"



# Your document html
  ExpiresByType text/html                 "access plus 0 seconds"

# Data
  ExpiresByType text/xml                  "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xml           "access plus 0 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/json          "access plus 0 seconds"

# RSS feed
  ExpiresByType application/rss+xml       "access plus 1 hour"

# Favicon (cannot be renamed)
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon              "access plus 1 week"

# Media: images, video, audio
  ExpiresByType image/gif                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/png                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg                "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType audio/ogg                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/mp4                 "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType video/webm                "access plus 1 month"

# HTC files  (css3pie)
  ExpiresByType text/x-component          "access plus 1 month"

# Webfonts
  ExpiresByType font/truetype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType font/opentype             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/x-font-woff   "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType image/svg+xml             "access plus 1 month"
  ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject "access plus 1 month"

# CSS and JavaScript
  ExpiresByType text/css                  "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript    "access plus 1 year"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript           "access plus 1 year"

  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header append Cache-Control "public"
  </IfModule>

</IfModule>
```

You can get more information on at http://www.paulund.co.uk/set-expire-headers-in-htaccess

Comment: I already had the `ExpiresByType mime/type... "access plus 1 year"` stuff but I didn't have the global `ExpiresActive on` set. That did the trick!